# How to keep account active in WIX despite closing tab

Tags: velo

I currently created a website in WIX platform and it contains a login and registration web pages, but my main problem is once I logged in and closed the tab, it tells me to login again, my question is there a way to keep the login account active even when I close the tab?

Comment: You had to save authorization credentials using eighter `cookies` or `localStorage`. Saying auth creds I mean token or something else that backend requires for authorization.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)